# Using ContentBlockByKey to populate part of URL inside a href

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

%%=ContentBlockByKey('tracking')=%%https://www.google.com?%%emailname_%%

The link ends up not converting to "click.e...." like regular URLs after sent. Is there a way to get the URL to convert by only editing the content block rather than re-writing the entire URL with AMPscript?

For instance, the following works but would require updating each URL with RedirectTo() and CONCAT():

%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT(ContentBlockByKey('tracking'),'https://www.google.com?',emailname_))=%%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly right. Email rendering does not understand what links to track when you insert dynamic parts. The only way around this is wrapping the link (or all relevant links) with RedirectTo (plus concat).

Unfortunately, the RedirectTo MUST be inline (meaning inside %%= =%% ), and cannot be made part of a variable's value like

```
/* this does NOT work */
%%[
SET @completeLink = <a href='RedirectTo("https://www.google.com")'>test</a>
]%%
```

Some sources:

[AMPScript Link Tracking - Does RedirectTo has to be Inline? Understanding](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300752/ampscript-link-tracking-does-redirectto-has-to-be-inline-understanding)

http://www.josyulablog.com/how-to-track-dynamic-content-click-through-sent-via-content-builder/

There is the "httpgetwrap" workaround involving support, but specifically note its limitations, which makes its scope rather small. Maybe it can help your case where links are created manually and you are not sending triggered sends or journeys (the limit applies per jobId, and those two keep their jobId over a longer period).

[Dynamic trackable links in ExactTarget email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32329/dynamic-trackable-links-in-exacttarget-email)

That aside, just recently we went to great lengths isolating several links inside a large portion of content coming from a feed using looped string operations, as there seems to be no way around the "RedirectTo must be inline rule".