# Interpret Ampscript variable saved in a data extension field value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, email-template

I'm facing an issue trying to evaluate a `concat`ampscript function and variable saved in a data extension attribute.

I tried to evaluate them with `treatAsContent` function but it's still not evaluated.
Also tried to use get and setValue in SSJS.

(I MUST manage the text wording in the data extension)

[image: Data Extension]

```
  %%[ var @MyAccountURL, @lang, @Body
    set @MyAccountURL = "https://www.levana.io/"
    set @lang = "US"
    
    set @Body = Lookup('NL_Registration_Content_Copy',@lang,"Email_Variable_Name", 'Body')
   
    ]%%
    
    <br> @lang =<br> %%=v(@lang)=%%
    <br><br> @MyAccountURL =<br> %%=v(@MyAccountURL)=%%
    <br>
    <br><br> Body = <br> %%=v(@Body)=%%
    <br><br> BodyTreatAsContent  = <br> %%=v(treatascontent(@Body))=%%
```

The Output is :

> @lang = US
>
> @MyAccountURL = https://www.levana.io/
>
> Body = concat("Your Account link is : ",@MyAccountURL," .")
>
> BodyTreatAsContent = concat("Your Account link is : ",@MyAccountURL,"
> .")

Comment: Why don't have the text only in DE and just have conact in the ampscript?

Comment: If you want that link to be functional and tracked, you will have to split the DE content so that the link is on its own and can be wrapped in ana tag and a redirectTo() function. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/326137/using-contentblockbykey-to-populate-part-of-url-inside-a-href/326151#326151 - or do you simply want the URL to be there as a piece of non-clickable text?

Comment: @SwatiMishra - I noted that this is my UseCase. The client will manage change many times the traductions.

Comment: @JonasLamberty - the link is just an exemple, I will have standard fields like FirsName, LastName...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need ampscript tags in your data extension field contents. For example for US should be

```
%%=concat("Your Account link is : ",@MyAccountURL," .")=%%
```

Instead of

```
concat("Your Account link is : ",@MyAccountURL," .")
```